# Append function appends list sometime as row and sometimes as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I am reading a file that contains a group of sequential numbers. I am grouping each sequential number into one list and then adding them to a bigger list. I found that the append function group the number sometimes as a row and others as a column like that

> [[366.0, 367.0, 368.0, 369.0, 370.0, 371.0, 372.0, 373.0],
>
> [473.0, 474.0, 475.0, 476.0, 477.0, 478.0, 479.0, 480.0, 481.0],
>
> [693.0, 694.0, 695.0, 696.0],
>
> [718.0, 719.0, 720.0, 721.0, 722.0, 723.0],
>
> [1036.0,
>
> 1037.0,
>
> 1038.0,
>
> 1039.0,
>
> 1040.0,
>
> 1041.0,
>
> 1042.0,
>
> 1043.0,
>
> 1044.0,
>
> 1045.0],
>
> [1080.0, 1081.0, 1082.0, 1083.0, 1084.0, 1085.0, 1086.0, 1087.0],
>
> [1424.0, 1425.0, 1426.0, 1427.0, 1428.0, 1429.0, 1430.0, 1431.0],
>
> ...

[Here is the link for the datafile](https://app.box.com/s/75rt7aik0s9m80vsrifl6ww40cp3u4xp)

Any ideas.
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
i4whole=np.loadtxt('MJO_events.txt')

j=0
uu=[]
uu_final=[]
for i in np.arange(len(i4whole)-1):
    if ((i4whole[i+1]-i4whole[i]) == 1):
        #print(i4whole[i])
         uu.append(i4whole[i])
    else: 
        uu.append(i4whole[i]) # print the last number in the groub
        uu_final.append(uu)
        uu=[]
        j=j+1 #  to count the number of  group
uu.append(i4whole[i+1])
uu_final.append(uu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. Lists aren't "rows" or "columns"; they're just lists, regardless of what whitespace is used to arrange their elements visually when displaying them. What you're seeing is IPython (probably IPython, anyway) displaying long lists with one element per line for readability.

Comment: I found that by doing simple print as the following all sublist were printed nicely looks like rows. `for i in uu_final: print (i)`